# how can I see data for last month in Fabric Answers? Or is it just for last 30 days overview

Tags: google-fabric

how can I see data for last month in Fabric Answers? Or is it just for last 30 days overview

I looked all documents on Fabric Answers website, blog and read almost every question here, but I have seen only data for 1 day, last 7 days or last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebase here - it depends what you're looking for. If you're talking about the active user categories, the dashboard will show you Daily Active Users (1 day), Weekly Active Users (7 days), or Monthly Active Users (30 days). If you just want Answers data that's more than 30 days old in general, you can actually export up to a year's worth of data directly from the Fabric dashboard for many different metrics. Check out this link for more information: https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/export-data.html. Hope that answers your question.